# Read xml with namespace

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

I can read a xml like this...

```
    var xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.Load(fileName);


    var myVal = SingleElement(xml, "BOOKS/AUTHOR/NAME")

    public string SingleElement(XmlDocument xdoc, string thePath)
    {
        string value;
        try
        {
            return xdoc.SelectSingleNode(thePath).InnerText;
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            value = string.Empty;
        }

        return value;
    }
```

But if the xml file has a namespace like `<ns0:BOOKS`

I get an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error. What Do I need to add in order to be able to read the xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use XmlNamespaceManager to add namespace.

```
XmlNamespaceManager namespacemgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
        namespacemgr.AddNamespace("ns", "xxx");
        XmlNode node = criteria.SelectSingleNode("/ns:Books", namespacemgr );
```